# Combining data from Sql Server and Graph database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2014, graph-databases, sql-graph

In my C# project I have relationship stored in graph database and I want to pull the data based on relationship from Sql Server, which is my main data base.

What would be the best approch to pull the data fron these two databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the SQL Graph Architecture is introduced starting from SQL Server 2017+, we will see a lot of new features over time. As of now, there is a known issue. No support of Cross-database queries on graph objects.

> One of the approaches might be to have data redundancy in the Graph
>   database and entirely shift to it going forward.

**[Limitations and known issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-architecture?view=sql-server-2017#limitations-and-known-issues)**
There are certain limitations on the node and edge tables in this release:

1. Local or global temporary tables cannot be node or edge tables.
2. Table types and table variables cannot be a node or edge table.
3. Node and edge tables cannot be a system-versioned temporary table.
4. Node and edge tables cannot be Memory-Optimised tables.
5. Users cannot update the $from_id and $to_id columns of an edge using UPDATE statement. To update the nodes that an edge connects, users will have to insert the new Edge pointing to new nodes and delete the previous one.
6. It doesn't support Cross-database queries on graph objects.